# Inaccurate data about getHighestRow()

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am trying to get the last row that contains data in an excel workbook the problem is in some sheets i get the correct data but in other sheets i don't , i tried to change my code by using `getHighestDataRow()` instead of `getHighestRow()`   but i keep getting the same results so i updated my PHPExcel library from PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc to PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc but the same result too .
any ideas ?

i am thinking to make an if statement in a loop to test each row if it is empty or not .

```
     $lastRowt = $excel2->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow();
      echo" $lastRowt ";
```

`$lastRowt` keep getting 34 but it is only 30 .

```
    <html>
    <?php

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    ini_set("memory_limit",-1);

    require_once 'PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
     require_once 'include/adb.php';

    $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $excel2 = $excel2->load('try.xlsx');


    $sheetCount = $excel2->getSheetCount();
    for ($x=0; $x<$sheetCount; $x++) {
    echo"now $x <br>";

    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex($x);

     $objWorksheet = $excel2->getActiveSheet();

     $po  =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 7)->getValue();
     $in  =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, 7)->getValue();

    $id = date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,                 8)->getValue()));


     $esv =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, 19)->getValue();
     $won =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 21)->getValue();
     $DTH =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 21)->getValue();
     $wn  =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, 21)->getValue();
     $rco =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, 21)->getValue();
     $wc  =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, 21)->getValue();
     $rch =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, 21)->getValue();
     $wd  =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 22)->getValue();
     $cs  =   1 ;



     $query="INSERT INTO invoice 
    (saponum, invoicenum, invoicedate, esvnum,workordernum, dth, wellnum, regcode, wellcharge,         rigcharge, workdescription, idc)VALUES 
    (  '$po',      '$in',       '$id', '$esv',      '$won','$DTH', '$wn',  '$rco',      '$wc',            '$rch',           '$wd', '$cs' )";
    echo" query  <br> $query <br>";
    mysql_query($query);


      $queryi="select idv from invoice where invoicenum = $in ";
      echo" query  <br> $in <br>haya de el qwery bta3et el idv $queryi ";
     $idnt = mysql_query($queryi);

     $outputidernt=mysql_fetch_array($idnt);
    extract($outputidernt);

     $lastRowt = $excel2->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow();
    echo"<br> $lastRowt <br>";
     $rn = 25 ;
     for($i=$lastRowt ; $i>=28 ; $i--){

     $qty  =        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $rn)->getValue();
            echo "qty = $qty";
     $item =        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $rn)->getValue();
            echo "item = $item";
     $describtion = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $rn)->getValue();
            echo "describtion = $describtion";
     $unit =        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $rn)->getValue();
            echo "unit = $unit";
     $pric =        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $rn)->getValue();
            echo "pric = $pric";
     $rn++ ;



     $queryit=" SELECT ids FROM pricelist WHERE itemnum = '$item' AND saponum = '$po' ";
     echo" queryit  <br> $queryit <br>";
     $idniter = mysql_query($queryit);

    $outputider=mysql_fetch_array($idniter);
    extract($outputider);


      $querys="INSERT INTO invoicestep ( ids , quantity , idv) VALUES ( '$ids','$qty','$idv' )";
    echo" querys  <br> $querys <br>";
    mysql_query($querys);

     }

     }






    ?>        
    </html>
```

Comment: `getHighestDataRow()` has worked correctly with every test I have ever executed against it. Unless you can demonstrate otherwise (e.g. a sample Excel file where it is clearly returning a wrong value) you're not providing anything like enough information to show that there could be a bug in the library. Note that a cell containing a single space, still contains data

Comment: i added all the page.

Comment: Adding all your code tells me nothing..... you've indicated that there is a fault in PHPExcel, that it can't count the rows correctly when it reads your `try.xlsx` file.... to debug that, I need try.xlsx, not to see your code

Comment: i know but i do not know haw to share this try.xlsx file

Comment: The old Codeplex site still has a file upload section - https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/10749

Comment: https://www.codeplex.com/Download/AttachmentDownload.ashx?ProjectName=phpexcel&WorkItemId=21415&FileAttachmentId=8682

this is the link to the try.xlsx

Answer (score 7):

I have ran into this issue before when getting the highest column and was due to formatting and formulas in cells. Even if the cell doesn't display a value, that doesn't mean the cell is empty. PHPExcel will read cells that appear empty, but actually have some formatting or formula within it.

If this is the case for you, you could clear out all formatting/formulas below your content. Sometimes this isn't feasible if the file is generated else where, so therefore I recommend adding the following line of code after you create the reader and before you load the file: `$excel2->setReadDataOnly(true);`

So that block of code should read as:

```
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2->setReadDataOnly(true);
$excel2 = $excel2->load('try.xlsx');
```

Comment: I´ve been getting rows with NULL values at every cell (maybe cause the have style or something), in any case, those cells contain nothing. Your comment fix my problem, thanks.